# Accessing outputs of Sensors of Samsung Gear VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, sensors, virtual-reality

Is there anyway I can access the outputs of IMU(Inertial Measurement Unit) of the Samsung Gear VR. Any API or guidance to how it might be done will be very helpful.

Comment: You have to stablish something, you want that the doctor can see the patience point of view, on RUNTIME, or can be something "recorded", and then see it when he wants?

Comment: I want both options. Live streaming will be very difficult with mobile VR which will already running VR applications therefore I only want to send strings(i.e outputs of sensors) to the doctor's side and then the doctor's mobile VR will simply process it and show the patients point of view

Comment: Sounds like a simple multiplayer setup: The doctor's camera transform is synced with the patients camera so he sees what the patient sees. (The doctor might also want to switch to a second overview camera he controls himself). The doctor could than also unlock certain hints/instructions or receive notifications about what the patient did. Overall an interesting case but unfortunately I would say it is to broad/off topic here on StackOverflow.

Comment: as derHugo says, seems a Multiplayer setup, the only question that you have to answer once again is, the doctor can see the patience actions after the patience? Or only at the same time (runtime)?

Comment: As I mentioned above that I want to give the doctor 2 options. 1) He can see the patience action at runtime. 2) The patient simulation is recorded and doctor can see it whenever he is free(not on runtime). The method I am thinking is that I want all the outputs from sensors and controllers to be send to the doctor's application which can then process it. Right now I am looking into Oculus Documentation and found something named OVRInput and VrApi which seem promising for my approach.